# Android spinner and the view.GONE when come to fill the data

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners, one of them may be visible and the other may be invisible that depends on the data, it's like a tree but represented in a spinner.

So I use `setVisibility(view.GONE)` to hide one of them, but I still need to fill it with some IDs and values that came from DB. It is only one value but I need to add it to the spinner, it is a future requirement.

So I need to get that value in the spinner?
How can i access it?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like if it wasn't "Visible.GONE", the View is still there, but hidden. You can access it and initialize it programatically

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Spinner is instantiate before you need to fill it with data, there is nothing to with the visibility. That instance is already in the memory you still can do operation on it.

Think like this:

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner); //we have the instance. in our xml its defined as `android:visibility="gone"`

//suppose you have the data in the cursor.
List l = new ArrayList();
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.isAfterLast==false)
{
    l.add(c.getString(0)); // add it to the list 
    c.moveToNext();

}
String[] mySpinnerArray = l.toArray();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mySpinnerArray);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You still have it

Comment: In this case, does the `setOnItemSelected` action will be fired? (if it is already registered) and even if the spinner have only one value?

Comment: Nope, sOIS() cannot be called because your view is not visible. If the view is visible then sOIS() will be fired even if you have 1 item.